# Question regarding memory allocation of variables in a structure (In C)

Tags: c, struct, structure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

struct word1{
 char a;
 int b;
 char c;
};

struct word2{
 char a;
 char b;
 int c;
};

printf("%d\t%d\n", sizeof(int), sizeof(char));   //Output : 4 1
printf("%d\t%d\n", sizeof(struct word1), sizeof(struct word2)); //Output: 12 8
return 0;
}
```

The code is available at [IDEONE](http://www.ideone.com/13Wlr).

Why is the size of struct 1 (word1) greater than the size of struct 2 (word2)?

Is this a compiler problem?

Comment: Don't use '`void main()`' and expect to be unshouted at - the correct return type for `main()` is `int`.

Comment: one day someone is going to claim that returning void instead of int caused a nuclear meltdown, or something.

Comment: OK, I'll take care of this from next time.

Comment: @Crashworks: maybe, but not by me. It means that there is no reliable value returned to the environment, so if program A is relying on the exit status of program B, it is undefined what value A will receive from B if B returns no value. Now, if the programs are anywhere near a nuclear pile, one would assume that the code reviews and testing and coding standards all ensure that no disaster happens. If beginners learn to return a value from main(), it helps get them ready to work in more demanding environments than classroom exercises. Eventually, they should read the C standard, but not yet.

Comment: Gotta be one of the most duplicated on-topic question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, I use `void main(void)` all the time. Saves several bytes of ROM and RAM on the AVR.

Comment: @Vorac: if you're working in a freestanding environment, or if the hosted environment specifically supports `void main()`, then fine.  However, in a general C question like this (one which doesn't stipulate a freestanding environment), then it is bad practice to use `void main()`; hence my comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `int` probably has a four-byte alignment requirement, so in the first case, both of the `char` elements need to have three padding bytes appended to them but in the second case you only need two padding bytes after the second `char` element (because a `char` element has an alignment of one byte).

`word1` looks like:

```
0   |1   |2   |3   |4   |5   |6   |7   |8   |9   |10  |11
a   |  (padding)   |b                  |c   |  (padding)
```

`word2` looks like:

```
0   |1   |2   |3   |4   |5   |6   |7
a   |b   |(padding)|c
```

Answer (score 4):

Case 1:

```
  0    1    2    3    4  
+---------------------+
| a    | Unused       |      4 bytes
+---------------------+

  0    1    2    3    4 
+---------------------+
|       b             |      4 bytes
+---------------------+

  0    1    2    3    4 
+---------------------+ 
| c    | Unused       |      4 bytes
+---------------------+
```

Total :  12

Case 2:

```
  0    1    2    3    4 
+---------------------+
| a   | b   | Unused  |      4 bytes
+---------------------+

  0    1    2    3    4 
+---------------------+
|       c             |      4 bytes
+---------------------+
```

Total : 8

P.S : [Structure Padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) is implementation defined.